# How to create an async event bus using RxJava 2?

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, rx-java2

Using RXJava 2, I'm trying to create an asynchronous Event Bus.

I have a singleton object, with a `PublishSubject` property. Emitters can send an event to the bus using `onNext` on the subject.

If subscribers have a long task to execute, I want my bus to dispatch the tasks on multiple threads to execute concurrently the tasks. Which means I want the work to start on an item immediatly after the item is emitted, even if the work on the previous item is not completed.

However, even using `observeOn` with a `scheduler`, I cannnot run my tasks concurrently.

Sample code:

```
public void test() throws Exception {
    Subject<Integer> busSubject = PublishSubject.<Integer>create().toSerialized();

    busSubject.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .subscribe(new LongTaskConsumer());

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " - event");
        busSubject.onNext(i);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

private static class LongTaskConsumer implements Consumer<Integer> {
    @Override
    public void accept(Integer i) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(i + " -   start work");
        System.out.println(i + " -     computation on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println(i + " -   end work");
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
1 - event
1 -   start work
1 -     computation on thread RxComputationThreadPool-1
2 - event
3 - event
1 -   end work
2 -   start work
2 -     computation on thread RxComputationThreadPool-1
4 - event
2 -   end work
3 -   start work
3 -     computation on thread RxComputationThreadPool-1
3 -   end work
4 -   start work
4 -     computation on thread RxComputationThreadPool-1
4 -   end work
```

Which means that the work on item 2 waited for the end of work on item 1, even if the event 2 was already emitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the call below happens one worker is created from `Schedulers.computation()` and is used for the whole stream. That's why all the of the work you submitted is done on `RxComputationThreadPool-1`.

```
busSubject.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .subscribe(new LongTaskConsumer());
```

To schedule work on multiple threads:

```
busSubject.flatMap(x ->
        Flowable.just(x)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()
            .doOnNext(somethingIntensive))
    .subscribe(new LongTaskConsumer());
```

Note also that the intensive work is performed inside the `flatMap` rather than in the `LongTaskConsumer` because all items will arrive serially to `LongTaskConsumer`.

There are other approaches to doing work in parallel that you may want to investigate depending on how many events are hitting the `PublishSubject`.

Comment: Thanks. `busSubject` being an Observable (`PublishSubject`); I had to use `Observable.just(...)` instead of `Flowable.just`. Besides, since the intensive task is performed inside `flatMap`, my `LongTaskConsumer` is useless: can I use `.subscribe()` (without consumer)?

Comment: Yep you could use `.subscribe()` and use the returned `Disposable` for cancellation purposes. However, that ignores errors so you would probably want to put a `.doOnError(e -> log.error(e))` before it for example.